# Sending Props to functional component : TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have custom Interfaces defined like so

```
interface Meeting {
    Subject: string;
    Organizer: string;
    StartTime: string;
    EndTime: string;
    Participants: Participant[] | null;
}

interface Participant {
    Name: string;
    Title: string;
}
```

then I have a

```
const meetings: Meeting[] = // array of Meeting objects
```

Now I try to send this like so

```
export const App = ():JSX.Element => {
    return <div className="app-container">
        <MainView info={meetings}/>
        <SideBar/>
    </div>

}
```

Error i get is for "info" , it reads

```
Type '{ info: Meeting[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Meeting[]'.
  Property 'info' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Meeting[]'.ts(2322)
```

What is wrong here and how can I send this prop ?

Also, in receiving component there is

```
export const MainView = ({info}: Meeting[]):JSX.Element => {return <></>}
```

and error is again at 'info'

```
Property 'info' does not exist on type 'Meeting[]'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the first argument in a JSX.Element refers to the entire `prop` object: so when you unpack the `info` key, you need to define the type as such:

```
export const MainView = ({ info }: { info: Meeting[] }):JSX.Element => {return <></>}
```

For better clarity, it makes sense to define the props for MainView separately:

```
interface MainViewProps {
  info: Meeting[];
}

export const MainView = ({ info }: MainViewProps):JSX.Element => {return <></>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Props is an object, and info is one property on that object. So you can specify the type like this:

```
export const MainView = ({ info }: { info: Meeting[] }): JSX.Element =>
```

Alternatively, there's a helper type `FC` for function components:

```
import { FC } from 'react';

export const MainView: FC<{ info: Meeting[] }> = ({ info }) =>
```

Note that the `FC` will automatically add `children` as a possible prop, which may not be desired.